# Using Django ORM, Iterate through table records, test them and delete the record if needed

Tags: python, django, datetime, orm, celery

How would you iterate through a table, using the Django ORM, and test the datetime fields to see if they are 8 days old, then delete them if they True.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_id = models.Charfield()
    tweet_date = models.DatetimeField()
```

---

```
# tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@shared_task(name='cleanup')
def cleanup():
    tweets = MyModel.objects.all()
    for tweet.tweet_date in tweets:
        if tweets.tweet_date <= datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8):
        # remove this record from the table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly query the database for more than 8 days old `tweets` using `lte` and delete the resultant `tweets`. There is no need of iterating over the results and then individually deleting all of them.

```
@shared_task(name='cleanup')
def cleanup():
    # filter and delete more than 8 days old tweets
    Tweet.objects.filter(tweet_date__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=8)).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks. This handles the cleanup and saves me some overhead.